# Custom modification of column values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table containing unique ids and amounts associated with them for a few years.

| ID | Year | Amount ($) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016 | 100 |
| 1 | 2017 | 45 |
| 1 | 2017 | 65 |
| 2 | 2017 | 75 |
| 2 | 2018 | 75 |
| 2 | 2019 | 80 |

I want to add $100 to amount for the first year of each ID, but only if the first year is greater than or equal to 2017. In this case i want $100 added to ID '2' and only for year 2017. This $100 is the extra amount for every ID in their first year on or after 2017.

| ID | Year | Amount ($) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016 | 100 |
| 1 | 2017 | 45 |
| 1 | 2018 | 65 |
| 2 | 2017 | **175** |
| 2 | 2018 | 75 |
| 2 | 2019 | 80 |

Is there an easy way to do this in pandas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean masks for indexing:

```
# is it the first row of the group?
m1 = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().eq(0)
# is the Year ≥ 2017?
m2 = df['Year'].ge(2017)

# add 100 in place
df.loc[m1&m2, 'Amount ($)'] += 100
```

output:

```
   ID  Year  Amount ($)
0   1  2016         100
1   1  2017          45
2   1  2018          65
3   2  2017         175
4   2  2018          75
5   2  2019          80
```